# Website doesn't scroll | Contents extend outside bottom of page | Footer appears on top

Tags: html, css, scroll, footer

### Problem 1: Scrolling/Showing contents

The page doesn't recognize the text and images within a div in the body. The text/images go outside the page on the bottom. They are visible if one zoom out. I tried to add a scrollbar, but scrollbar won't scroll because it doesn't recognize any content that has gone outside the page.

### Problem 2: Footer is at the top

Because the contents in the div are not recognized, the footer that should be on the bottom of the page ends up at the top like a header.

## The Codes:

```css
/* PARTS OF THE PAGE */
body
{
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    margin: 0px;

}

.sidebar {
    background-image: url(http://images.all-free-download.com/images/graphiclarge/blurred_golden_background_192849.jpg);
    height: 100%;
    width: 400px;
    border-right: 2px solid #ddd;
    position: fixed;
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
}

.maintext {
    margin-left: 450px;
    width: 600px;
    padding: 0px 50px 10px 50px;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: visible;

}

footer {
    padding: 10px;
    position: relative;
    background-color: red;

}

/* TEXT */
h1 {
    text-align: center;
    height: 30px;
    font-family: 'Imprint MT Shadow';
    font-weight: 100;
    font-size: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    letter-spacing: 20px;
    color: #fff7e6;
    text-shadow: 0px 1px 2px #706b51;
}

h2 {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Century Gothic';
    letter-spacing: 10px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    font-weight: 200;
}

p {
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: Calibri;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
}


.maintext p {
    padding-left: 30px;
    padding-right: 30px;
}

.quote {
    background-color: gray;
    margin: 0px 90px 0px 90px;
}

ul#menu li{
    display: inline;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    border-left: 1px solid #706b51;
    padding-right: 40px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-family: Candara;
    color: #706b51;
}

hr {
    margin: -10px 80px -10px 80px;
    color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="archive.css" />
    <title>title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="sidebar">
        <div class="maintext">

            <!-----------------The menu -------------------->
            <h1> header 1       </h1>
            <hr />

            <center>
                <ul id="menu">
                    <li>Link 1</li>
                    <li>Link 2</li>
                    <li>Link 3</li>
                    <li>Link 4</li>
                    <li>Link 5</li>
                </ul>
                <hr />
            </center>

            <!------------------The post ------------------->

            <h2> Title 2 </h2>
            <p class="quote"> This is a block with quote.</p>

        
                <p> Some more text here. The scrolling doesn't work, page doesn't recognize this as content. So if this text is looooong it will go outside the page from the bottom. <br>

Some more text here. The scrolling doesn't work, page doesn't recognize this as content. So if this text is looooong it will go outside the page from the bottom.<br>

Some more text here. The scrolling doesn't work, page doesn't recognize this as content. So if this text is looooong it will go outside the page from the bottom.<br>

Some more text here. The scrolling doesn't work, page doesn't recognize this as content. So if this text is looooong it will go outside the page from the bottom.<br>

Some more text here. The scrolling doesn't work, page doesn't recognize this as content. So if this text is looooong it will go outside the page from the bottom.<br>

Some more text here. The scrolling doesn't work, page doesn't recognize this as content. So if this text is looooong it will go outside the page from the bottom.<br>

Some more text here. The scrolling doesn't work, page doesn't recognize this as content. So if this text is looooong it will go outside the page from the bottom.<br>

Some more text here. The scrolling doesn't work, page doesn't recognize this as content. So if this text is looooong it will go outside the page from the bottom.<br>

Some more text here. The scrolling doesn't work, page doesn't recognize this as content. So if this text is looooong it will go outside the page from the bottom. <br>

Some more text here. The scrolling doesn't work, page doesn't recognize this as content. So if this text is looooong it will go outside the page from the bottom.<br>

Some more text here. The scrolling doesn't work, page doesn't recognize this as content. So if this text is looooong it will go outside the page from the bottom.<br>

Some more text here. The scrolling doesn't work, page doesn't recognize this as content. So if this text is looooong it will go outside the page from the bottom.<br>

Some more text here. The scrolling doesn't work, page doesn't recognize this as content. So if this text is looooong it will go outside the page from the bottom.<br>

Some more text here. The scrolling doesn't work, page doesn't recognize this as content. So if this text is looooong it will go outside the page from the bottom.<br>

Some more text here. The scrolling doesn't work, page doesn't recognize this as content. So if this text is looooong it will go outside the page from the bottom.<br>

Some more text here. The scrolling doesn't work, page doesn't recognize this as content. So if this text is looooong it will go outside the page from the bottom.<br>

Some more text here. The scrolling doesn't work, page doesn't recognize this as content. So if this text is looooong it will go outside the page from the bottom.<br>
</p>

            </div>
        </div>
</body>

<footer> <p> This is the footer. The page does not recognize any of the content within the body, so this ends up right at the top of the page. <b> JOY </b> </p></footer>

</html>
```

Comment: You have gotten it totally wrong. Footer is outside of body, that can't be. Also your problem is that your content is inside 'sidebar'

Comment: As @Akxe says, your html is incorrect - nothing can be outside the closing `</body>` tag and you do need to fix that. And it is odd to have all your content inside what you are calling a "sidebar". However neither of those are actually the *cause* of the problem - both are related, and are caused by the positioning you are using, as I've noted in my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

1. **Scrolling**

By using `fixed` and `absolute` positioning for the sidebar and maintext, you are taking those out of the flow of the page - i.e., you have taken *all of the content* out of the flow so there is nothing actually left in the flow except the footer, so there is nothing to scroll.

Just remove the positions from the CSS, i.e.

```
.sidebar {
    [...]
    position: fixed; /* <- remove this */
}

.maintext {
    [...]
    position: absolute; /* <- remove this */
}
```

2. **Footer at top:**

As you have taken all of the content out of the flow so there is nothing actually left in the flow except for the footer, which is why it appears at the top. Fixing the above will fix that issue.

Note: Also, as has been stated in the comments, nothing should be outside the ending `</body>` tag, so move your footer inside the body element

**Working snippet:**

```css
/* PARTS OF THE PAGE */

body {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  margin: 0px;
}

.sidebar {
  background-image: url(http://images.all-free-download.com/images/graphiclarge/blurred_golden_background_192849.jpg);
  height: 100%;
  width: 400px;
  border-right: 2px solid #ddd;
  background-repeat: repeat-y;
}

.maintext {
  margin-left: 450px;
  width: 600px;
  padding: 0px 50px 10px 50px;
  overflow: visible;
}

footer {
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: red;
}


/* TEXT */

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  height: 30px;
  font-family: 'Imprint MT Shadow';
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  letter-spacing: 20px;
  color: #fff7e6;
  text-shadow: 0px 1px 2px #706b51;
}

h2 {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Century Gothic';
  letter-spacing: 10px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  font-weight: 200;
}

p {
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: Calibri;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

.maintext p {
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 30px;
}

.quote {
  background-color: gray;
  margin: 0px 90px 0px 90px;
}

ul#menu li {
  display: inline;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  border-left: 1px solid #706b51;
  padding-right: 40px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-family: Candara;
  color: #706b51;
}

hr {
  margin: -10px 80px -10px 80px;
  color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="archive.css" />
  <title>title</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="sidebar">
    <div class="maintext">

      <!-----------------The menu -------------------->
      <h1> header 1 </h1>
      <hr />

      <center>
        <ul id="menu">
          <li>Link 1</li>
          <li>Link 2</li>
          <li>Link 3</li>
          <li>Link 4</li>
          <li>Link 5</li>
        </ul>
        <hr />
      </center>

      <!------------------The post ------------------->

      <h2> Title 2 </h2>
      <p class="quote"> This is a block with quote.</p>


      <p> Some more text here. The scrolling doesn't work, page doesn't recognize this as content. So if this text is looooong it will go outside the page from the bottom. <br> Some more text here. The scrolling doesn't work, page doesn't recognize this as
        content. So if this text is looooong it will go outside the page from the bottom.<br> Some more text here. The scrolling doesn't work, page doesn't recognize this as content. So if this text is looooong it will go outside the page from the bottom.<br>        Some more text here. The scrolling doesn't work, page doesn't recognize this as content. So if this text is looooong it will go outside the page from the bottom.<br> Some more text here. The scrolling doesn't work, page doesn't recognize this
        as content. So if this text is looooong it will go outside the page from the bottom.<br> Some more text here. The scrolling doesn't work, page doesn't recognize this as content. So if this text is looooong it will go outside the page from the
        bottom.<br> Some more text here. The scrolling doesn't work, page doesn't recognize this as content. So if this text is looooong it will go outside the page from the bottom.<br> Some more text here. The scrolling doesn't work, page doesn't recognize
        this as content. So if this text is looooong it will go outside the page from the bottom.<br> Some more text here. The scrolling doesn't work, page doesn't recognize this as content. So if this text is looooong it will go outside the page from
        the bottom. <br> Some more text here. The scrolling doesn't work, page doesn't recognize this as content. So if this text is looooong it will go outside the page from the bottom.<br> Some more text here. The scrolling doesn't work, page doesn't
        recognize this as content. So if this text is looooong it will go outside the page from the bottom.<br> Some more text here. The scrolling doesn't work, page doesn't recognize this as content. So if this text is looooong it will go outside the
        page from the bottom.<br> Some more text here. The scrolling doesn't work, page doesn't recognize this as content. So if this text is looooong it will go outside the page from the bottom.<br> Some more text here. The scrolling doesn't work, page
        doesn't recognize this as content. So if this text is looooong it will go outside the page from the bottom.<br> Some more text here. The scrolling doesn't work, page doesn't recognize this as content. So if this text is looooong it will go outside
        the page from the bottom.<br> Some more text here. The scrolling doesn't work, page doesn't recognize this as content. So if this text is looooong it will go outside the page from the bottom.<br> Some more text here. The scrolling doesn't work,
        page doesn't recognize this as content. So if this text is looooong it will go outside the page from the bottom.<br>
      </p>

    </div>

  </div>
  <footer>
    <p> This is the footer. The page does not recognize any of the content within the body, so this ends up right at the top of the page. <b> JOY </b> </p>
  </footer>
</body>


</html>
```